# counting measure I need help

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Let $\mu : {\mathcal{P}} $($\mathbb{N}$) $\to$ [$0$,$\infty$] be the counting measure on the measurable space ($\mathbb{N}$,$\mathcal{P}$($\mathbb{N}$)) and let

$$
f:\mathbb{N} \to [0,\infty]
$$
be an illustration.

Show that that $f \in M_{+}(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ and compute
$$
 \int_{\mathbb{N}} f d\mu
$$

Comment: Can you explain what is $M_+$  ?

Comment: I edit this post, please edit it again with more details. They are very important to solve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $f \in M_+(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ means that f is measurable in that measure space of the power set of the natural numbers. What is an ilustration function?

Is $f: (\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})) \to (\mathbb{R}_{\infty},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_{\infty}))$ ??

If so, then $f$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ whenever
$B \in (\mathbb{R}_{\infty},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_{\infty}))$

Also I from what you write I can guess that

$\int_{N}f d\mu = \infty$.

Comment: no f is just a function f:IN -> [0,\infty]

Comment: I know, that's what I write, but I wanted to know which sigma algebras we are working. We can define measurability in terms of the sigma algebra and pre images.

Comment: More over the integral I think is which is the value of $\mathbb{N}$ under the counting measure alef 0.

Comment: Can you help me with that too? and thanks for the other one.

Comment: Please use the LATEX code for your questions. It's difficult to understand what you write.